# Resize (restyle) QWizard under OS X

Tags: qt, pyqt, pyside

The default look of a Mac wizard (and by extension of QWizard) is this:

[image]

All this space on the left, where the bowtie image is, is completely useless and wasted.
Instead I like what the Dropbox guys have done:

[image]

How do I achieve this effect in Qt?
(Using PySide wrapper here, but I'll take any code that I can get!)

I tried settings all kinds of paddings and margins and whatnot on QFrame, QWidget, etc. using a stylesheet and still cannot get rid of this space on the left. Do I need to hack MacStyle? How would I go about doing this?

Comment: I also asked this question on a Qt forum : http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/57268-How-to-remove-BackgroundPixmap-from-MacStyle-QWizard . No response so far.

Answer (score 1):

Change the Wizard Style to Classic:

```
setWizardStyle(QWizard::ClassicStyle);
```